# Find node of Treeview using data of gridrow

Tags: delphi, datagrid, treeview, vcl, treenode

First of all, I have a database: It can be either file or folder/map with these items (more columns are in the table, but I doubt they are required for this)

```
id | name | parent_id
----------------------------
1  | A    | nil
2  | A1   | 1
3  | A2   | 1
4  | A21  | 2
5  | B    | nil
6  | C    | nil
7  | C1   | 6
```

I have succeeded in making the tree by using a recursive query and function.
Adding a node requires the parameters of (aParent, aString, aPointer):

```
Treeview.Items.AddObject(nil, qry.FieldByName('name').AsString, Pointer(qry.FieldByName('id').AsInteger))
Treeview.Items.AddChildObject(aParent, qry.FieldByName('name').AsString, Pointer(qry.FieldByName('id').AsInteger))
```

This all works fine (of course the actual code is larger, but my question is the following. I have a datagrid in use which shows my files and folders. Opening a folder/map in my datagrid or treeview refreshes my datagrid and shows the correct items within. However when I change folder i want my treeview to change and select the correct node as well.

All I have found is that I can select nodes by index, but I dont know the index of the node I want to go to. I do this at load so it always starts at the first node:

```
tvProjectDocuments.FullCollapse;
tvProjectDocuments.Selected:=tvProjectDocuments.Items[0];
tvProjectDocuments.Items[0].Selected:=true;
```

Now my question, I am able to use the pointer of my node to get the correct data in my datagrid, but is it possible to find a node by pointer(id)?

UPDATE:
I managed to find the node by now

```
function TForm.FindNode(id: integer): TTreeNode;
var
  i: integer;
  found: boolean;
begin
  Result:=nil;
  i:=0;
  found:=false;
  while (i<Treeview.Items.Count-1) and not found do
  begin
    if Integer(Treeview.Items[i].Data)=id then
    begin
      result:=Treeview.Items[i];
      found:=True;
    end;
    inc(i);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm.tvProjectDocumentsChange(Sender: TObject; Node: TTreeNode);
begin
  if FFolderId = 0 then
  begin
    FFolderId:=Integer(Node.Data);

    //some code to get my grid filled data. works
    grid.Refresh;
    FFolderId:=0
  end;
end;

procedure TForm.GridCellDblClick(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer);
begin
  FFolderId:=<CustomComponent>.FieldByName('proj_document_id').AsInteger;
  Treeview.Selected:=(FindNode(FFolderId));

  //other stuff happens
  FFolderId:=0;
end;
```

When it comes to the last Treenode, i get this access violation while debugging: FFolderId:=Node.Data 
in the Watch list it nil.

Afterwards it does load my datagrid, but it does not select the node corresponding to what should be. 
With all other nodes if i open a folder from datagrid, it does select and show the proper node.

I have prevented the error for now by using the FFolderId. But it still doesnt select my last node. Any info would be appreciated.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have the pointer *to* the node (presumably stored in the table?) and want to use this to select the node. Is that correct? If so, say your pointer is called MyP, just use **(MyP as TTreeNode).Selected := TRUE;**

Comment: Although it is correct. id would be my pointer to the node i want selected. 
I tried taking your code, but could you elaborate? taking it as is doesnt work. (MyP is replaced by my own variable i already have in use which refers to the id in table)

Comment: OK you are referring to an ID, not a pointer (or at least not a pointer to a node, which was what I was asking). I wasn't clear on that point. How you proceed depends on whether you are rebuilding the tree from scratch. Are you? BTW you don't need both 'selected' statements, either one will do.

Comment: The tree is build in runtime depending on the project i opened and what kind of documents i want. thats the base filter to get the folders i want for my Tree. Then using the code, i add pointers to my nodes when i create them. When clicking such a node, i fill my datagrid based on the pointer that was given to that node. When clicking the record in datagrid (which is a folder) i need to find the node. While toying around, i actually have come so far that i can actually find my node and select it, but when it comes to the final node, i get an access violation. (ill edit original question, few m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selecting a node via its object can be achieved like this:

```
function TForm10.GetNodeFromObject(const pNodes: TTreeNodes;
  pObject: TObject): TTreeNode;
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to pNodes.Count - 1 do
  begin
    Result := pNodes.Item[ i ];
    if Result.Data = pObject then
    begin
      exit;
    end;
  end;
  // else
  Result := nil;
end;
```

You would then use it something like this

```
var
  iNode : TTreeNode;
begin
  iNode := GetNodeFromObject( TreeView.Items, Pointer( qry.FieldByName('id').AsInteger));
  if assigned( iNode ) then
  begin
    iNode.Selected := TRUE;
  end;
end;
```

in your case. Of course the function is more general than that.